# Cancel reverse numbers from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, reverse

Say I make a list of positive integers according to some criteria, as showed in the lines below:

```
N = 100
List_1 = range(12, N, 1)

# Cancelling multiples of 10
List_2 = [x for x in List_1 if x%10]

# Cancelling palindromic numbers
List_3 = [x for x in List_2 if str(x)!=str(x)[::-1]]
```

Therefore, my last list (`List_3`) obtained is:

```
[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 32, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 41, 42, 43, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 52, 53, 54, 56, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 68, 69, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 78, 79, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 89, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98]
```

Now, I would like to cancel from this list **all** numbers which are **reverses** of **previous** numbers in the list, for example:

cancel `21` as `21` is reverse of `12`, previously in the list.

cancel `31` as `31` is reverse of `13`, previously in the list.

etc...

cancel `98` as `98` is reverse of `89`, previously in the list.

So that finally, the list should reduce to (`List_4`):

```
[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 56, 57, 58, 59, 67, 68, 69, 78, 79, 89]
```

I didn't find a way to do this properly, apart from doing loops on the list to test if a number is the reverse of a previous one, which is not very effective. Any idea to get this `List_4` in a more "pythonic" way?

Comment: So you want all reverse from List_2, and you want to remove those from List_3?

Comment: I want to find reverse numbers in List_3 and remove them from List_3 to get a List_4

Comment: Note that `List_1` is a `range`, not a `list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to look at this is that any element that you reverse (`13`->`31`) will have a position in the list, and you only want to keep the ones that have a lower index:

```
List_4 = [x for x in List_3 if List_3.index(x) < List_3.index(int(str(x)[::-1]))]
```

Which translates roughly as:

> For each element in the list, take it unless you find its reversed somewhere earlier in the list.

Other probably better variation, just keep the smaller number:

```
List_4 = [x for x in List_3 if x < int(str(x)[::-1])]
```

#### Result

```
[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 56, 57, 58, 59, 67, 68, 69, 78, 79, 89]
```

#### Other considerations

There is another way to generate `List_4` as it currently stands:

```
List_4 = [10*x+y for x in range(1,10) for y in range(x+1,10)]
```

> Thanks to `wjandrea` pulling me out of `strings`

Comment: Nice pythonic way!

Comment: Easier to do the math in the other way: `[x*10+y for x in range(1,10) for y in range(x+1,10)]`

Comment: @wjandrea Indeed :) Got stuck thinking with `str` :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list with single loop by adding some if conditions.

```
res = []
for n in range(12, N):
    r = int(str(n)[::-1])
    if n not in res and r not in res and n != r and n%10:
        res.append(n)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 56, 57, 58, 59, 67, 68, 69, 78, 79, 89]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Pythonic and effective

```
List_4 = list({min(x, int(str(x)[::-1])) for x in List_3})
```

### Explain

We map any number `x` to `min(x, int(str(x)[::-1])` which is the smaller one between the number and its reverse. Thus 12 and 21 are all mapped to 12. We construct mapped numbers to a set so duplicated numbers are canceled. Finally we convert the set back to a list.

It's effective for we need only one-pass scan on the original list.

Comment: Nice! This makes it easy to do the whole thing in one loop. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/9fbd1d733293ef9136405f399ddfcadc). Feel free to add it into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
N = 100
List_1 = range(12, N, 1)

# Cancelling multiples of 10
List_2 = [x for x in List_1 if x%10]

# Cancelling palindromic numbers
List_3 = [x for x in List_2 if str(x)!=str(x)[::-1]]

list_4 = []
for n in List_3:
    if int(str(n)[::-1]) not in list_4:
        list_4.append(n)
```

Comment: Nice one. You could probably just `append(n)` instead of `append(str(n))` and then convert to `int` later. The lists all start with `int`.

Comment: ah yeah i just realised :)

Answer (score 1):

For improved efficiency, the resulting list can be built (and filtered) in a **single pass**.

Filters:

- Not divisible by 10
- Non-palindromatic
- Does not already exist in its palindromatic form

Example:

```
N = 100
l = []
for i in range(12, N):
    p = str(i)[::-1]
    if all([i % 10, 
            str(i) != p,
            int(p) not in l]):
        l.append(i)
```

Output:

```
[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 23, 24, 25, 
 26, 27, 28, 29, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 45, 
 46, 47, 48, 49, 56, 57, 58, 59, 67, 68, 69, 
 78, 79, 89]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```py
>>> List_4 = list(map(str, List_3))
>>> [List_4.remove(i[::-1]) for i in List_4 if i[::-1] in List_4]
>>> List_4
[12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 56, 57, 58, 59, 67, 68, 69, 78, 79, 89]
>>>
```